# ASP.NET Core await WebSocket.ReceiveAsync Prevents IIS from Closing dotnet.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, websocket, async-await

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 site.  It uses WebSockets, specifically `System.Net.WebSockets`.  The WebSocket system in general works very well.  But when I try to stop the site from IIS or stop the application pool from IIS, dotnet.exe keeps running.  I have to end the process with Task Manager for the site to be truly stopped.

After a lot of trial and error, I found dotnet.exe will stop normally if I deactivate the code that handles WebSockets.  But when I use WebSockets, the site will not stop when requested from IIS.  When using WebSockets, execution waits here:

```
result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Normally, I would expect execution to wait here.  But since the application is stopping, I need this `ReceiveAsync` call to return.  I'm wondering if I need to use a `CancellationToken`, but to do that, I need to use the *correct* `CancellationToken` of course.

Can someone recommend how to handle such a situation so that the await operation can end gracefully when the site or application pool is stopped from IIS?  Thank you.